# PHP snippet in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a page on my wordpress website that will display content based on which user is logged in.
I should be able to run a php script with *is_user_logged_in()* and a few others to get the job done.
Problem is that it doesn't matter what method I tried, it does not run any PHP whatsoever.
even

```
<?php
    echo "hello";
?>
```

Blandly pasted in the page editor, in an HTML widget, in two different PHP snippet plugins (XYZ PHP code & Code snippets): nothing. The code doesn't even show in the code of the page loaded in the browser.

I would love to be able to solve this.

Comment: The plugins don't work? They are supposed to ease the process of creating shortcodes, so that when you use `[shortcode id=123]` in your post , it is replaced by the php code you defined for it

Comment: Not working. I don't know if it is because I am trying to use them in a page rather then a post, but it just doesn't display any code.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to add PHP to a wordpress page. But let's focus on the relatively easy "shortcode" way.
If you have access to file `functions.php` of the theme, you can define your shortcodes (and their matching php functions you define) there. Just add to that file:

```
add_shortcode('banner', 'a1234_my_banner_shortcode');
function a1234_my_banner_shortcode($arr_attr, $content) {
  // do something in PHP and optionally `echo` something back.
  $param1 = $arr_attr["param1"];
  if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    return "hello logged in user number $param1";
  } else {
    return "hello guest number $param1";
  }
}
```

Then in your post, page or whatetver:

```
Hello world,
[banner param1=12]
Did you see that?
```

Comment: While this would work, it might be a good idea to add some sanitization / escaping to the code to avoid its misuse by malicious users.

Comment: @cabrerahector this won't work correctly, since shortcodes shouldn't echo output. BTW - I like your popular posts plug-in.

Comment: Ah right, I missed that detail. Yes, the shortcode should _return_ data, not _echo_ it. And thank you, glad you like my plugin @HowardE!